# Is there a client side API for handling transients or options?

Tags: javascript, block-editor, api

After having some trouble with the [ServerSideRender sending a request with headers too large for the nginx server to handle](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368327/how-to-get-a-more-significant-error-response-from-serversiderender), I wonder if I can avoid using the ServerSideRender callback. In my ServerSideRender callback I am saving options, and reading / writing transients. Can this be done from the client side javascript for a Gutenberg block? Is there a javascript API for reading / writing transients and reading / writing options?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [REST API endpoint for settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/settings/) that can be found at `/wp/v2/settings`

Comment: Seems that the Settings API only accounts for a set of predefined site wide settings, not for handling registered settings (which are often linked with options). I guess ServerSideRender will have to do for now (and btw the problem I was having with ServerSideRender has been confirmed and is being patched, so once it's patched it'll probably still be the way to go)

Comment: You can define custom options and access them via the REST API but if you have a solution then great!